# Matlab mode tab completion kills frames in emacs

Tags: matlab, emacs, autocomplete

I use the MATLAB mode for Emacs as described [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2009/09/14/matlab-emacs-integration-is-back/).

My problem is the following:

I have several frames open, one on the left, running the `matlab-shell`, and one on the right showing my code.
When I am in the `matlab-shell` and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> for auto-completion, if there are several choices, Emacs will show those in my right frame. When I continue typing until the word is unique, and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> again, the right frame is closed. This is very annoying as I have to reopen the frame and change the buffer almost every time I hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> for auto-completion.

Any hints on how to make this work like standard auto-completion (like for file names when opening files) does, where the frame is used, and as soon as the completion succeeds the frame status returns to the same situation it was in before the completion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is almost certainly a serious bug with Matlab mode — which means, unfortunately, that the only fix will be to go into its Emacs Lisp code and reform it so that it handles transitory window creation and deletion properly, instead of trying to use the other open frame without knowing whether it really owns it or not.

**Edit:** Here is its bug tracker, by the way: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=154105&atid=790446